# How can I get colors from an image?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I get colors from an image? Like [this site](http://www.cssdrive.com/imagepalette/index.php) does? I want to know how I can get that.

Comment: This question needs a lot more explanation for what you want to do and what question you're asking.  As it stands now, there is not enough information to answer.  Voting to close.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041399/how-to-use-javascript-or-jquery-to-read-a-pixel-of-an-image

Comment: First result in google was http://hungry-media.com/2010/09/html5canvas-fun-extracting-colors-from-images/.  Try to show some research effort before posting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get image color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746530/get-image-color)

Answer (score 1):

here is a Image Color Extract is based on a PHP Class by Csongor Zalatnai  http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3370-PHP-Extracts-the-most-common-colors-used-in-images.html

Online Example 
http://www.coolphptools.com/color_extract

You can use it to extract color profile in HEX format