# get the first pixel from the image using php

Tags: php

I am trying to get the first pixel of the image. preferably, the one very top left or right pixel. 
I saw this question and it has the closest answer to my question : [Get image color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746530/get-image-color)

However, the answer only shows you how to get the average color. I do not want to get the average color, I want to get the first pixel from any side! anybody know of a way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i get pixel value of image in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172115/how-can-i-get-pixel-value-of-image-in-php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this, it gets the color of the top-left pixel (0,0):

```
<?php
    $im = imagecreatefrompng("image.png");
    $rgb = imagecolorat($im, 0, 0);

    $colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);

    var_dump($colors);
?>
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php