# How can I get the pixel value of image in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to use PHP to read every pixel in a image. It's for graphical password project. When user chooses a password, they will select some area on the image. and I'm trying to do it by pixel value. Is it possible??

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, you can get the pixel "value" as in color using [`imagecolorat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php).

```
$color = imagecolorat($resource, $x, $y);
```

Where `$resource` is your image resource, and `$x`, `$y` are the coordinates of the pixel you want to get the color of.

You can iterate through all of the pixels like this. Note that this can be an expensive task depending on how large the image is.

```
$width = imagesx($resource);
$height = imagesy($resource);

for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
    for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
        // pixel color at (x, y)
        $color = imagecolorat($resource, $x, $y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice that this may return either 1) the index of color at that pixel 2) actual color at that pixel. If You use imagecolorsforindex(), You can be sure that You get RGB values.

Comment: @GintareStatkute *the string* as in the image path?

Answer (score 0):

@GintareStatkute If you have the image content as a string you can use:

```
<?php
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
   . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
   . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
   . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$data = base64_decode($data);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
```

If you have the file path instead, then use any of the creation functions, such as imagecreatefromgif(), imagecreatefromjpeg(), imagecreatefrompng().