# Get effective color of background image after filter via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a full-page background image that changes often. It has a CSS3 gaussian blur filter on top of it.

How can I obtain the effective color (the color rendered) at any given pixel?

I need to compute the average color of the background which affects other CSS parameters.

Comment: Since the image is on the server, it will be easier and solve the performance issues to do it server side and display the result.

Answer (score 0):

How is this for an answer? Sounds like images have to be from the same domain but I am assuming you're doing this any way.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17789253/5750070

Comment: I saw this answer and I'm worried about poor performance (usability and battery life for mobile users)