# How to get outline coords of images?

Tags: javascript, php, svg

I have some problem for me, how I can find coords of outline image?
For example, i have picture like this
[image: image for example]

and i want to have outline coords for next using in svg path d.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789076/get-pixel-color-from-an-image)

In your case, I think it is better to use "Nested for Loops" and check each pixel. If the pixel has no RGB values, then it is the mask.