# Getting the color of a pixel on an image

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, web, colors

I've been trying to figure out a solution to a problem I am having. I simply just want to get the color of a specific pixel on a JPEG in JavaScript. Is there a good way I can do this? All solutions I find online talk about manipulating a canvas, or changing the colors of a canvas element, but I simply want to find a pixel color on an image.

Thank you for any help and insight!

Comment: This might help [get pixel color from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789076/get-pixel-color-from-an-image)

Comment: Drawing the image on a canvas and then reading off the area you want is pretty standard as a pure JS way of getting the color. Is there a problem with doing that in your situation?

Answer (score 3):

Since you included *node.js* in your question tags, i'll do this in *node.js* rather than the browser.

You can use [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) to get a pixel color from a JPG.

```js
import Jimp from 'jimp';

const image = await Jimp.read('./Lenna.jpg');

console.log(Jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(0, 0)));
```

You can output the color value in various formats, in the example above I used `Jimp.intToRGBA` to get the value `{ r: 226, g: 137, b: 125, a: 255 }`

Which you can see in the background if you run the code snippet below.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(226, 137, 125, 1)
}
```

It looks the same as in the top left corner of the image below:

[image]