# How to get color of an image in js or node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, image

I want to get color of some pixels of an image by js or node.js.
How can I do?

I want to find color of every pixels of a png image for choosing pixels with special color in the image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72082372/getting-the-color-of-a-pixel-on-an-image, and https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-image-colors

Comment: You will need to tranfer the PNG to a HTML `<canvas>` and read/manipulate the canvas pixels. MDN has a nice reference page with examples on the subject: [Pixel manipulation with canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas).

Comment: Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas