# Detect background color of png image has grey or not with php

Tags: php

I am trying to find background color of png images having grey color or not.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The above link says overall colors of an image. But i need to find background color of an image

Comment: Okay, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810199/php-how-to-detect-if-image-contains-color

Comment: Show one example image

Answer (score 0):

If you speak about background-color of images in html, jquery can do the trick:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="image.png" id='image_id' style="background-color:Gray;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
console.log($('#image_id').css('background-color'));
if( $('#image_id').css('background-color') == 'rgb(128, 128, 128)' ) {
   console.log('Gray!');
} else {
   console.log('Not gray');
} 
</script>
```

Comment: If possible can you help me with PHP as i have 50,000 images to check which i cannot use jquery

Comment: You need to check files on disk, am i right?

Comment: I need to run the script in backend for optimization

Comment: So, these images are stored on the disk as separate files? You need to check background-color property of images in html pages?

Comment: I am not storing the images, i am having the URL's of images

Comment: That doesn't really get the background of *images* but the CSS background property assigned to image *tags*. The two are different - the image would be the actual file fetched and displayed by the browser. On a different note `'rgb(127, 127, 127)' would also be gray. As would many other variations, like `'rgb(127, 128, 129)'`

Comment: Thus you will need to get every image using file_get_contents and apply method described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746530/get-image-color. Don't forget about max_execution_time in ini file. And the last - PHP isn't suited for long running tasks.